# Building a page that shows a photo like photo app (zoom and pan)

Tags: swiftui

How to build a page that works exactly like the Photo Apps of the iOS that can zoom into a photo using MagnificationGesture() and can pan after zoom using Pure SwiftUI?

I have tried to look for solutions in the forum, yet, none of question has a solution yet. Any advise?

Here is my code:

```
        let magnificationGesture = MagnificationGesture()
          .onChanged { amount in
              self.currentAmount = amount - 1
          }
          .onEnded { amount in
              self.finalAmount += self.currentAmount
              self.currentAmount = 0
          }
      
      let tapGesture = TapGesture()
          .onEnded {
              self.currentAmount = 0
              self.finalAmount = 1
          }
      
      Image("Cat")
          .resizable()
          .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
          .frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
          .scaleEffect(finalAmount + currentAmount)
          .simultaneousGesture(magnificationGesture)
          .simultaneousGesture(tapGesture)
```

Originally, I tried to add 1 more simultaneousGesture, dragGesture() which adjust the offset, but it fails to work.

The current code zoom the image well, but after zoom in, I want it to be allowed to pan. I have tried to add UIScrollView it also fails.

Here is my thought:

```
let dragGesture = DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in self.offset = value.translation }
```

and to add .offset() to the image.
However, it fails to work and the simulator is out of memory.

Any advise?

Comment: Try using a LazyVGrid and adjust the number of columns in relationship to the MagnificationGesture()

Comment: I am not looking for a grid view, but zoom and pan gesture in swiftui

Answer (score 1):

Use `DragGesture()` with `position`.
Tested Xcode 12.1 with iOS 14.2 (No Memory issues.)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var currentAmount: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var finalAmount: CGFloat = 1
    
    @State private var location: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
    @GestureState private var startLocation: CGPoint? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        let magnificationGesture = MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged { amount in
                self.currentAmount = amount - 1
            }
            .onEnded { amount in
                self.finalAmount += self.currentAmount
                self.currentAmount = 0
            }
        
        // Here is create DragGesture and handel jump when you again start the dragging/
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                var newLocation = startLocation ?? location
                newLocation.x += value.translation.width
                newLocation.y += value.translation.height
                self.location = newLocation
            }.updating($startLocation) { (value, startLocation, transaction) in
                startLocation = startLocation ?? location
            }
        
        return Image("temp_1")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .scaleEffect(finalAmount + currentAmount)
            .position(location)
            .gesture(
                dragGesture.simultaneously(with: magnificationGesture)
            )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible not to allow the user to move the image out of the UIScreen using your method?

Comment: The code does not work when the image is out of the screen or when the user scale too small. the centre position of the image may change and the image disappeared

Comment: I have just added solutions based on your question. Why Simultaneously gestures not work. For further and based on your requirements you have to modify this code. And you have to use scroll view and mange all things

Comment: Please add minimum scale constraints and manage all scenarios. We are not do the whole functionality here

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the issue with UIViewRepresentable.

```
struct ImageScrollView: UIViewRepresentable {

private var contentSizeWidth: CGFloat = 0
private var contentSizeHeight: CGFloat = 0
private var imageView = UIImageView()
private var scrollView = UIScrollView()

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ImageScrollView>) -> UIScrollView {

    let image = UIImage(named: "Dummy")
    let width = image?.size.width
    let height = image?.size.height
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width ?? 0, height: height ?? 0)
    imageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = true
    scrollView.bouncesZoom = true
    scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5 //scrollView.frame.size.width / (width ?? 1)
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2
    scrollView.zoomScale = 1
    
    scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
    
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    
    
    let doubleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleTap(sender:)))
    doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)

    return scrollView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView,
                  context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ImageScrollView>) {
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var control: ImageScrollView
    
    init(_ control: ImageScrollView) {
        self.control = control
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("scrollViewDidScroll")
        centerImage()
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView,
                            with view: UIView?,
                            atScale scale: CGFloat) {
        print("scrollViewDidEndZooming")
        print(scale, scrollView.minimumZoomScale, scrollView.maximumZoomScale)
        scrollView.setZoomScale(scale, animated: true)
        centerImage()
    }
    
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.control.imageView
    }
    
    
    func centerImage() {
        let boundSize = self.control.scrollView.frame.size
        var frameToCenter = self.control.imageView.frame
        frameToCenter.origin.x = 0
        frameToCenter.origin.y = 0
        if (frameToCenter.size.width<boundSize.width) {
            frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundSize.width-frameToCenter.size.width)/2;
        }
        if (frameToCenter.size.height<boundSize.height) {
            frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundSize.height-frameToCenter.size.height)/2;
        }
        self.control.imageView.frame = frameToCenter
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if (self.control.scrollView.zoomScale==self.control.scrollView.minimumZoomScale) {
            self.control.scrollView.zoomScale = self.control.scrollView.maximumZoomScale/2;
        } else {
            self.control.scrollView.zoomScale = self.control.scrollView.minimumZoomScale;
        }
        print("tap")
        
    }
}
```

}